# SQL Server - SKIP DML statements from a given SQL Script file

Tags: sql, sql-server, operation, dml

I have a huge sql server script which has mix of ddl, dml operations and there is a requirement to create a clean db structure (with no data). Is it possible for a transaction to skip DML scripts through some parameter or some other way.

Thanks in Advance.

Arun

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box: no. But you can wrap the DML statements in your script with something like:

```
if ($(RUNDML) = 1)
begin
   --your dml here
end
```

Where RUNDML is a [sqlcmd variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx). You'd invoke your script with differing values of RUNDML based on whether or not you wanted data in the database being built.

Alternatively, separate the DML out into another script (or scripts) so you can choose whether to run the data portion of the build or not.

Comment: hi Ben, thanks for your reply - there are 300+ files and it will not be possible to split it. Is there a way to do this while restoring DB like Oracle has imp utility where data=N

Comment: SQL Server backup and restore doesn't allow for this. You could try doing a comparison of this database with an empty one using either SSDT or a third-party tool (I use Red Gate's SQL Compare) and apply the differences to the empty database.